# Getting "killed" trying to install Ionic on Cloud9

Tags: ide, ionic-framework

I am getting the error "killed" when trying to install Ionic on Cloud9 using a free account.

Attempting "npm install -g cordova ionic" results in "killed" . The workspace comes with 512mb RAM, 1GB HDD and 1 CPU.

Surely this is enough to run such a simple command?

Are there any other online IDEs that work with Ionic?

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting the following command which should have worked fine on a free plan

npm install -g cordova ionic

However, splitting it "npm install -g cordova" and then doing the ionic package afterwards with "npm install -g ionic" resulted in successful installation.

Answer (score 0):

"npm config set jobs 1" and combination with new workspace (1GB RAM) did work for me ;) link: https://community.c9.io/t/npm-install-is-killed/847